# Sending JSON to Java post and displaying info

Tags: java, apache, http, post, http-post

I am trying to send the following JSON string to a url in Java:

Where tag name is `data` and the body is

```
{"process": "mobileS","phone": "9999999999"}
```

The code that I have so far is the following:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("url goes here");
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity("details={\"process\":\"mobileS\",\"phone\":\"9999999999\"}");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setEntity(params);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    System.out.println(response);

    // handle response here...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); //Deprecated
}
```

I am supposed to get a JSON string from the above after sending that JSON data to the server, but I don't know where to go after sending the above request.

The good thing is that the response gives back a 200 response and it shows all the other information that would normally come from the result of HttpResponse, but I am to get a result similar to:

```
{"test": {"this is":"what I am supposed to get"}}
```

So basically it should return a JSON string and I am getting something completely different from what I need

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0,post-check=0, pre-check=0 etc etc etc
```

I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true

Comment: @immibis thanks bud! but I am not a developer by trade and scrapping what I already wrote took me a good deal of effort and self learning. I got placed on a very peculiar position in which I am tasked with doing things I have no clue about. For what little I read, the above is one out of a billion ways in which data can be sent as a post request, I guess I could try every method you linked me to but I have no clue as to which one would serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HttpResponse`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true) class exposes a [`getEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity()) method which returns an [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) instance. That provides a mechanism for accessing the reponse content.

You can use [`EntityUtils`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) to retrieve and consume the content stream for the entity:

```
private void getData(){
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;

    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("url goes here");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("details={\"process\":\"mobileS\",\"phone\":\"9999999999\"}");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setEntity(params);

        response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response);

        // handle response here...
        if (successful(response)) {
            entity = response.getEntity();
            String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            System.out.println(content);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity);
        if (response != null) response.close();
        if (httpClient != null) httpClient.close();
    }
}

// TODO Customize for your server/interaction
private boolean successful(HttpResponse response) {
    return response != null 
            && response.getStatusLine() != null 
            && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;
}
```

Comment: If I read along the logic stands good but when I run it I still don't get the response I am trying to get, nothing comes out.

Comment: @sigillum_conf Are you able to debug and confirm that the response is being sent back successfully (i.e. that you're receiving a 200 OK (or similar) as opposed to a 400/500 type error)?

Comment: indeed, I am getting a 200 response

Comment: @sigillum_conf And the response isn't blank? Is it just a blank line being printed out to the console? Does your debugger tell you the value of `content` before it's printed?

Comment: yes, the response is not blank, and the content displays a carriage return '\r' inside content before it prints. I added additional print statements to check as well as using intellij's debugger and can see that the response evaluates to what I posted originally in the question.

Comment: and I think I got it now!! Going through the debugger helped me figure out what it was(the JSON content I was passing had details instead of "data" which is what my company's API is currently using for this request example) and I got it working now, thank you so much!!